# Fusing multiple foldl' in Haskell

Tags: loops, haskell, lazy-evaluation, fold

I'm trying to read and analyse a huge CSV file. I used `Data.Csv.Streaming` from cassava, and functions are applied in the following order:

```
Data.ByteString.Lazy.readFile -- Gives lazy stream
Data.Csv.Streaming.decodeByname -- Gives Either String (Header Records t)
\(Right (_, v)) -> v -- Gives right side of either (Records t)
Data.Foldable.toList -- Gives [t]
```

After this the program enters the analysis stage, and executes **four** (this is very important) different instances (i.e. with different filters) of the following

```
filter -- Result of toList is applied through a filter
map
Data.Foldable.foldl' -- Does bin counting using a map. The map has at most 60 keys.
```

However, it appears that the program takes up a huge amount of memory while attempting to load the entire CSV file.

If I only have one instance of foldl' executing, the program does a nice single pass through the CSV data and doesn't consume as much memory. Is there a way to fuse the foldl's together? That is, having

```
x = foldl' f Map.empty $ filter cx li
y = foldl' f Map.empty $ filter cy li
...
```

and force it to execute in single pass.

Edit: The following function is used in `foldl` with `Data.Map.Strict` as `Map`:

```
bincollect :: Ord a => Num b => Map.Map a b -> a -> Map.Map a b
bincollect !m !key = Map.insertWith (+) key 1 m
```

and the foldl begins with an empty map.

The memory usage grows with the number of elements `take`d with or without optimization on.

Comment: `fold'` is a strict function.
You may want to take a look at `foldr` instead

Comment: This is du to `foldl'`. In fact `foldl'` is the *non-strict* version of `foldl`.

Comment: @Welperooni `foldl'` doesn't need the whole list to be loaded into memory. Replacing it with the regular `foldl` still gives the same memory usage.

Comment: If your list is only passed to `foldl'`, it should be OK. `foldl'` will need to scan the whole list, but it can be garbage collected while this is done if no one else is using the list. However, be sure that the function you pass to `foldl'` is suitably strict, so that you do not end up with a huge thunk. E.g. you final 60-key map could be storing lazy thunks instead of evaluated counts. Perhaps you should post the `foldl'` code.

Comment: Have you imported the strict version of the `Map` module?

Comment: @Welperooni Yes. `Data.Map.Strict`

Comment: Am I the only one here thinking that strictness is not to blame? The red flag for me is this sentence: "After this the program executes four different instances of the following...". Unless you are re-reading the file and re-parsing it after each instance, you won't be able to garbage-collect already-processed parts of the file, so of *course* it will force the whole thing into memory. But to know for sure what's going wrong, we need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah, I missed that part. That's definitely a big red flag.

Comment: @DanielWagner The four instances of filter are executed together (and are identical except for the filtering function) so I would expect the compiler to fuse the loops.

Comment: @HenricusV. My expectation differs from yours. See also [Beautiful Folding](http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html) and its Hackage incarnation, [folds](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/folds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can indeed fuse the four folds together, but you'll have to do it manually. You could try and write out the logic yourself, or you could use a library (like [foldl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.0/docs/Control-Foldl.html)) to help. For instance, you can turn your bincollect into a fold:

```
bincollect :: (Ord a, Num b) => Fold a (Map.Map a b)
bincollect = Fold (\m key -> Map.insertWith (+) key 1 m) Map.empty id
```

Then, you can filter using `prefilter`:

```
x = prefilter cx bincollect
```

Finally, you can combine them together using the `Applicative` instance:

```
(w,x,y,z) = fold ((,,,) <$> prefilter cw bincollect
                        <*> prefilter cx bincollect
                        <*> prefilter cy bincollect
                        <*> prefilter cz bincollect)
                 input
```